# How can I not declare what type of a class C#

Tags: c#, class, input, types, constructor

I have created a class to implement the QuickSort algorithm on an array.This is the constructor and the variables of the class :

```
public class QuickSort
{
    int[] numbers;

    public QuickSort(int[] input) {
        numbers = input;
        Console.WriteLine("QuickSort created!");
    }
```

But I want to use it for arrays of other types, like float.
How can I declare the class so that it can take as input an array of any type? 
thanks

Comment: Have you looked at generics? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is more difficult than it seems.

First, there's already two answers here that says to use generics.

For the given code example, they're 100% correct, use generics.

But that alone won't give you the answer to how to proceed.

First, using generics will give you the ability to write a quicksort class or method that will accept any type of value.

However, it won't necessarily tell you how to actually do the sorting, when your sort method can take any type of value.

Here's how *I* would declare the stuff from your question:

```
public class Quicksort
{
    public void Sort<T>(IList<T> collection)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Without posting the actual implementation of the quicksort method, the benefits would be:

- Can accept any type of value, as `T`
- *Provided* that the `T` knows how to compare itself to other `T`'s (`where T : IComparable<T>`), meaning that if you are sorting int's, any one int can tell you whether it comes before or after, or is the same as, any other int.
- Taking `IList<T>` means that you can take any pre-indexable type of collection of `T`'s. Quicksort usually relies on being able to know how many elements are in the collection to sort, and `IList<T>` is the smallest type in the .NET collection world that can do so (unless you cound `IList`, the non-generic interface).

Questions only you know the answer to:

- Why did you make `numbers` an *instance* variable of `QuickSort`? Why do you need instance variables at all?

Comment: The instance variable is not necessary you are right. I'll expirement with your solution and I hope I can do what I want. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
public class QuickSort<T> where T : IComparable<T>
```

You'll have to use the `IComparable<T>` interface instead of the comparison operators for your sorting purposes.

Or just:

```
public class QuickSort<T>
```

But then you'll have to use an `IComparer<T>` in the algorithm. You can get the default one for type `T` with: `Comparer<T>.Default`

Either way, the standard comparison operators (`<`, `>` etc) won't work with a generic type.

Comment: You should change `where T : IComparable` into `where T : IComparable<T>`. There is no need to use the non-generic `IComparable` interface since .NET 2 (2005).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant actually, but I forgot the `<T>`, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics:

```
public class QuickSort<T>
{
  T[] numbers;

  public QuickSort(T[] input) {
    numbers = input;
    Console.WriteLine("QuickSort created!");
}
```